# netbeans platform add 'org-netbeans-modules-lexer.jar' dependency

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-8

I added this 'org-netbeans-modules-lexer.jar' dependency to a netbeans platform module. But it seems not getting added in the normal way. Imports cannot find its classes as well.

This is how it is shown when added. Any suggestion? Netbeans version 8.0.2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click main project properties -> select libraries -> expand 'ide' in platform modules list -> select Lexer module to be included in the project. This resolves the issue.

This method is general for adding any dependencies that can be found only by ticking 'Show Excl. Modules' in dependency adding dialog which can be opened by project module properties -> libraries -> module dependencies -> add dependency.